# Classification using ANN

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, emgucv

Hi wlel I am doing a project to recognize a pen using ANN with emgucv C# visual studio 2010. I have a question about ANN. I must train ANN in order to recognize a pen. So I have one neuron in ouput layer for two classification(a pen or not pen) So I train ANN with 1100 image of pens and my question is: Do I need to train ANN with any images that is not a pen for the second class(first class is a pen) or If I show a image that ANN was not trained, ANN will assume that is not a pen?

Comment: If you only train your ANN on images of pens, it will assume every image is an image of a pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Beaker points out, it will assume everything is a pen. However, you can use the level of the output to predict how likely it is to be a pen. But what you really want to do is to train it on pens and non-pens. You may also see better performance with 2 outputs nodes, one for pen and one for not pen. That is typically how people do NN classification, although using a single should work. Be aware that your choice of activation function will guide the range of inputs and outputs between nodes (sigmoid expects 0-1, tanh -1 to 1). Also, the number of levels of the network and the number of neurons in each hidden layer can make a big difference. Make sure you have at least one hidden layer. It is unlikely to do well if you have an input and output layer only.

I would use some online images of random objects to train the negative cases, if you have none. However, as you seem to have a usage of this in mind, giving it images close to the ones it will see when used after training will result in better performance.

Comment: yes first I convert images to grayscale then apply GaussianBlur to remove noise and then convert in binary images is that good?? and So I have an idea I want to use background of pen like negatives images is that a good idea?

Comment: mmm For example if ANN recognize a pen How can I draw a rectangle in place where pen is??

Comment: Unsure. That's really a different type of problem. You may be able to solve that with an ANN. I would probably try a clustering approach to segment the image, given your ANN thinks it's a pen. But I see that as a different problem.

Comment: mm OK. I read about to normalize values between 0-1. Is there any problem with values 0-255 of grayscale images in order to give to ANN like inputs??

Comment: If they are normalized, no, in theory. However, binarizing them so that you convert them to a simple 0,1 (using a threshold) may work much better. I have heard people using whitening a lot when trying to solve this problem, e.g. http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/4985/what-exactly-is-whitening

Comment: So if I try to give ANN values between 0-255 Will I have bad result? is that a bad idea??

Comment: Depends on your activation function but yes. The logistic function, for instance, has a very low gradient at inputs greater than 6: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function so it is very hard to do gradient ascent quickly over such a slight gradient. You are always better scaling all your features to the same range. But 0-1 (sigmoid) or -1 to 1 (tanh) is probably best.

Comment: hey.If I use images of apples in order to be recognized by ANN , so if images contain 2 or more apple ANN tell that images contain apples?? or onnly recognize one object inside images

Comment: It's gonna find it harder, but it depends on the image.